# custom cursor not showing on custom button

Tags: c++, winapi

I registered a custom button in `WM_CREATE` but my custom cursor resource is not recognized and I am getting a double arrow cursor when hovering over the custom buttons that I create at run time.  Any solutions? I have included `resource.h` and triplechecked that the custom resource with `IC_CURSOR2` is there in the resources.

```
        WNDCLASSEX buttonx; //subclass our custom buttons
        buttonx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        GetClassInfoEx(NULL,TEXT("BUTTON"), &buttonx);
        buttonx.lpszClassName = "CustomButton";
        buttonx.hInstance = hInst;
        buttonx.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR2));
        RegisterClassEx(&buttonx);

        hButton1 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "CustomButton", "Close", WS_CHILD 
            | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 410, 570, 100, 30, hWnd, 
            (HMENU)ID_BUTTON1, g_hInstance, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting a double arrow cursor

That sounds like one of the stock cursors, like IDC_SIZENS.  Which indicates that you *hInst* variable is NULL.  Maybe you should have used g_hInstance, it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: thanks Hans I changed hInst to global g_hInstance and it solved my problem! :)